# Should I use threadpool,threads or backgroundworker with System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, threadpool, task-parallel-library

```
public class JobRunner
{
    internal Timer Timer;
    internal readonly IEnumerable<YuartzJob> Jobs;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.Timer = new Timer(5000);
        this.Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        this.Timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Timer.Stop();
    }

    internal void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var job in Jobs)
        {
            MyActivator.RunJob(job);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivator
{
    public static void RunJob(YuartzJob job)
    {
        var objectHandle = Activator.CreateInstance(job.AssemblyName, job.ClassName).Unwrap();
        var currentJob = (IJob)objectHandle;
        currentJob.Run();
    }
}
```

How should I do where I used MyActivator.RunJob(job):

1. Should I call MyActivator.RunJob by using ThreadPool ?
2. Should I call MyActivator.RunJob by using Threads ?
3. Should I call MyActivator.RunJob by using BackgroundWorker ?
4. Does it work this way without doing anything?

Comment: Do you want to run the jobs in parallel? The current solution executes them synchronously on a separate thread

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Yes, I want to run the jobs in parallel.

Comment: If your jobs take longer than 5sec the timer will still fire and jobs will be queue up infinitely.

Comment: Use a high level library! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting .NET 4 the easiest way is to use Tasks. Tasks execute a method using threads from the ThreadPool. The .NET runtime (actually, a TaskScheduler) makes sure the threadpool is not exhausted by too many tasks:

```
    foreach (var job in Jobs)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>MyActivator.RunJob(job));
    }
```

Tasks also allow for easy cancellation, exception handling and chaining which is not possible when using the ThreadPool or your own threads.

For earlier versions you should consider ThreadPool first and only create your own threads if the jobs are so many and long running that they risk exhausting the threadpool:

```
    foreach (var job in Jobs)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>MyActivator.RunJob(job));
    }
```

Backgroundworker is considered obsolete in .NET 4+ and only suitable for very coarse-grained parallelism anyway. In your case you would have to create a separate worker for each job, subscribe to its events, run it and clean up after it.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is not officially obsolete and I'd say you shouldn't consider it to be obsolete either. It still has its uses in GUI applications, especially if you want to report progress from the background task to the UI thread.

Comment: I've been reading Albahari's C#5 lately, guess it affected me. Anyway, .NET 4.5 has the IProgress interface and related classes for this job. If you use .NET 4.5 or the Async CTP you no longer need BW.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process a collection of items efficiently in parallel, my first choice would be something that was made exactly for that purpose: [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx).

Internally, it uses `Task`s, which means it will run on the `ThreadPool`. It also tries to use `Task`s efficiently, so if you have a collection of with a million of items, it won't create a million `Task`s.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach will also block until all jobs have finished. This may or may not be desirable, depending on the scenario or the job itself. BTW it's probalby a better option to use a full-featured scheduler like Quartz.NET instead of hand-coding one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it will block, but I think that's okay in this case, because it's started from a `ThreadPool` thread (because of `Timer`). And I think using something like Quartz.NET might be an overkill here, but I never used it.

Answer (score -1):

The .NET Framework provides four timers. Two of these are general-purpose multithreaded timers:

- System.Threading.Timer
- System.Timers.Timer

The other two are special-purpose single-threaded timers:

- System.Windows.Forms.Timer (Windows Forms timer)
- System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer (WPF timer)

So if you want your method to be executed in multi-threaded way/parallel then you have to go for the one among first two.

Find more about this along with sample source code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer)

Comment: The OP already uses System.Timers.Timer. What he asks is how to fire off all jobs in parallel